# let shade plugin ignore a war file but copy it into uberjar

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin, hawtio

I want to bundle hawt.io into my Java application (hawtio-default-1.4.45.war). To make it user friendly i just copied the war into resources.

The problem is, I use shade plugin to create the jar and it seems that it fiddles around with the embedded war - hawt.io is working fine if main() is started from within eclipse but it is completely messed up if i start my jar.

Is there a way to let shade plugin ignore the war (it's contents) but just copy it into the jar?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to see how hawtio build its hawtio-app which is a standalone JAR that embed hawtio and the WAR, and you can configur the main class and whatnot.

See: https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/tree/master/hawtio-app

Comment: sorry Claus but i don't understand what do you suggest. i don't have problem with configuring hawt.io but i need to know how to embed the war or the jar and let shade ignore it. I just tried not embedding it but put it besides the jar - this is working fine

Comment: as i see hawt-app uses assembly plugin but i use shade plugin because i need correct handling of special resources that some dependencies use (cxf...)